# 2 column layout with an extra scroll bar for left column using only css

Tags: html, css

I have a list of flatterned div elements (Unfortunately I can't edit html markup to add structures). Because the div#1 is very long, I'd like to put it in a seperate column with its own scrollbar; all the other div's (the number of div's is flexible) are stacked in the right column. What is the best css setting to achieve this? Ideally, I don't want to use fixed/absolute position.

```
<div id='1'>1</div>
<div id='2'>2</div>
<div id='3'>3</div>
.
.
.
<div id='n'>n</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello RNA , you want to use pure html and css? or any framework which you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to achieve this result check this [example](https://codepen.io/makraz/pen/vYOvzWz):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column div {
  background-color:#bbb;
  height:50px;
}

.column div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div style="height:500px;">div 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
   <div>div n</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All the divs are in the same container. and I can't edit html markup. so I can't add "column"-class divs.

Comment: you can check this [solution](https://codepen.io/makraz/pen/OJVrqOz)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this structure for this. In this I used the `display:flex` property so you don't need to use any position.

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
}

.blue {
    height: 600px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.red {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="blue"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="red"></div>
            <div class="red"></div>
            <div class="red"></div>
            <div class="red"></div>
            <div class="red"></div>
            <div class="red"></div>
            <div class="red"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: All the divs are in the same container. and I can't edit html markup. so I can't add "left" -and "right"-class divs

Comment: "right" and "left" class is optional. if you want to remove these class you can, but  you need give first child of div inside the unique class so you will be add scroll in particular that div.